# How does one get the value passed to JavaScript's Callback.invoke()

Tags: javascript, react-native

I can't get value from the following code in JavaScript.

**Here my code:**

```
public void isEnabled(Callback isEnabled) {
    isEnabled.invoke(wifi.isWifiEnabled());
}
```

How do I get at the return value of the expression `wifi.isWifiEnabled()` in JavaScript (react-native)?

Comment: What library are you using for `wifi`?

Comment: I used react-native-wifi module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code is part of the library's [implementation](https://github.com/blackdeve/react-native-wifi/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/reactlibrary/RNWifiModule.java#L163-L167). To get the value passed to `invoke`, consume the module at its API level.

```js
WifiManager.isEnabled(bool => {/* do stuff with wifi enabled */})
```

If you need this as a promise, you can create your own `isWifiEnabled` that returns a Promise

```js
const isWifiEnabled = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  WifiManager.isEnabled(bool => resolve(bool))
})

isWifiEnabled().then(bool => {/* stuff with wifi enabled */})
```